# Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x) f(2^2x) f(3^2x) \cdots f(n^2x) = 0$ for $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here's another question that I'm stuck on from my studies for an upcoming exam.  This one comes from another practice preliminary exam.

**Problem**

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be  a Lebesgue integrable function.  Prove that for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x) f(2^2x) f(3^2x) \cdots f(n^2x) = 0$$

I.e. given that $\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)| dx < \infty$, prove the above limit.

Please, correct me if I'm wrong, confirm my thoughts, or provide hints towards a solution.  Thanks in advance!

**My Partial Attempt**

> Break the support into three cases.  Either $S := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) \neq 0\}$ (1) has $\mu(S) = 0$, (2) finite $\mu(S) > 0$, or (3) $\mu(S) =  \infty$,.
>
> (1) We have immediately that the integral $\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)| dx = 0$ because the function is supported by a set of measure zero.  Hence, the function is zero almost everywhere and we have our result.
>
> (2) This is the tricky case for me.  This is where I'm looking for guidance if my case-by-case method is in fact a method for solution.  Otherwise, provide a hint or an alternative solution method.
>
> (3) Help here too.

Comment: (3) is incorrect; for example the pdf of a continuous distribution is integrable.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Bingo, you're absolutely right.  Can't believe that I made that mistake.  I'll edit the question. With that comment and a few more thoughts I'm betting this has to do with the function's behavior at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $j=1,2,\dots$ and $\epsilon>0$, define

$$A_j^\epsilon  = \{ x: |f(j^2 x)|>\epsilon\}.$$

This is a measurable set.  We know

$$ \epsilon m (A_j ^\epsilon) \le \int |f |(j^2 x ) dx = \frac{\int |f| (y) dy}{j^2}=\frac{c}{j^2}.$$

Therefore $m (A_j ^\epsilon) \le \frac{c}{j^2\epsilon}$.

Write $A_j = A_j^{1/\sqrt{j}}$. Then $m (A_j ) \le \frac{c}{j^{3/2}}.$

Now let $A=\limsup_{j} A_j = \{x: |f(j^2 x) |\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\mbox{ for infinitely many }j\mbox{'s}\}$

It follows from the  [Borel-Cantelli lemma for general measure spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) that

$$ m (A)=0.$$

On the complement of $A$

$$|f(j^2 x)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}},$$

for all $j$ large enough (depending on $x$), and the result follows.